# Efficient way to return a part of array (from index)?

Tags: c#, arrays

There is an array of ints, where I am interested in those that start from index 10. Therefore, I am writing a method that would return a new array, which consists of 11th and further elements.
I tried the Array.Copy but it does not have the option I need. What would be the best way for this?

Comment: Array is `IEnumerable` so use `Skip()` and `Take()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [ArraySegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var source = new int[20];
var segment = new ArraySegment<int>(source, 10, source.Length - 10);
```

This is lightweight struct and it implements an `IEnumerable<T>` interface so you can use linq on it.

EDIT: In case you really need an array as return type you can create a new array with linq:

```
source.Skip(9).ToArray(); // skip from 0 to 9 and use a rest of source array
```

However this will allocate additional memory for array copy

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T[] SubArray<T>(this T[] data, int index, int length)
{
    T[] result = new T[length];
    Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
    return result;
}    

int startIndex=10;
    int[] data = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
    int[] sub = data.SubArray(startIndex, (data.Length-startIndex)-1));
```

Comment: There is no such method: `SubArray`.

Comment: thanks Dmitry, code of specified method have up-dated in posted solution.